# Is careers advertisement block being a-b tested?

Tags: support, jobs, advertising, testing

Usually, my side bar careers block is orange, but on some occurrence it's blue ! Is stack exchange proceeding to a-b testing to see which color is the best ? Is it random ? Is it based on some condition I couldn't find ? :D

This out of pure curiosity, I'm just wondering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, like many sites we sometimes conduct A/B tests like this. Right now, on Stack Overflow, some people will indeed see an orange version of the Careers ad in the sidebar, and other people will see a blue version.

Comment: Curious to know how you can know which is better? You monitor clicks in orange vs. blue colors?

Comment: I also see grey from time to time. I think I am A/B/C tested ;)

Comment: Does the color matter if I'm not looking for a job?