# For the love of god, please just pick a color for the job postings and stick with it!

Tags: feature-request, jobs, advertising

I don't know why, but the constant switching between orange and blue borders around your job postings is making me crazy.

e.g.

[image]                    [image]

For what it's worth, I am more likely to look at the orange ones.

Comment: Tempted to upvote just for hilarious title, but I shall restrain myself `:D`

Comment: You've just thrown a monkey wrench into their double-blind split A/B testing. And now that you've ruined their results, they'll have to wait at least two years before they can hope to redo/replcate this study from scratch.

Comment: Seems like an optimal time for a quick plug for this feature request - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175310/can-we-see-some-of-the-ab-testing-results-that-stackexchange-run (If it counts as a feature request).

Comment: Added screenshots, hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: GO TEAM ORANGE! I am so winning this bet...

Comment: @DavidFullerton personally, I also like the orange sidebar, it seems to complement the rest of Stack Overflow's theme (the orange in the logo, for instance). Though I've also clicked on postings in the blue sidebar.

Comment: That's the wrong shade of orange to be using to contrast with the white text, "Looking for a job?" bleeds terribly.  What succeeds about the blue isn't the color but the greater legibility, though the sharpness of the bars is a poor juxatposition to the blurriness of the adjacent text.  [See detail here.](http://metaeducation.com/media/shared/the-resolution/so-career-blur.png)  Sigh.  This is why I have trouble looking at the Internet.  *(Or going to restaurants in strip malls.  They have signage and menus, and I cry inside a little, even if it's good fried rice.)*

Comment: some sort of reference to Portal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Careers advertisements are [currently being A-B tested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230452/is-careers-advertisement-block-being-a-b-tested). Part of this was also discussed in the [recent podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/podcast-59-hes-one-of-those-science-ists/), if you're interested in that sort of a thing, and simply using the colours seems to have a significant effect. So more than likely you'll have to put up with it for a while until they settle on a final result.

Comment: Thanks, I actually heard the podcast, and in the spirit of the podcasts, I tried to use some sarcasm to get my point across that there may be some unintended consequences from this particular A-B test.

Comment: I accepted your answer, first, since you added useful info to clarify the situation and second, so that the question will be closed and I'll stop getting down-votes ;-)